# Black screen instead of multi-texturing

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have checked the textures individually, they work fine.
Each of the textures are 128*128 pixels, I am working on Motorola MILESTONE mobile,
and have tested all basic examples (from line to cubemap), got stuck while multitexturing
rectangle.

The shader works well if I do not bind any one of the textures, but the problem starts with two textures for multitexturing.

```
private float[] myRotateMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] myViewMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] myProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] myMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private int aPositionLocation;
private int uMVPLocation;
private int aTextureCoordLocation;
private FloatBuffer rectangleVFB;
private ShortBuffer rectangleISB;
private FloatBuffer textureCFB;
private int program;
private int textureId1;
private int textureId2;
private int uSampler1Location;
private int uSampler2Location;

private void initShapes()  {
    float[] rectangleVFA = {-1,-1,0,  1,-1,0,  1,1,0, -1,1,0};
    short[] rectangleISA = {0,1,2,  0,3,2};
    float[] textureCFA = {0,0,  1,0,  1,1, 0,1};

    ByteBuffer rectangleVBB = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(rectangleVFA.length * 4);
    rectangleVBB.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    rectangleVFB = rectangleVBB.asFloatBuffer();
    rectangleVFB.put(rectangleVFA);
    rectangleVFB.position(0);

    ByteBuffer rectangleIBB = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(rectangleISA.length * 2);
    rectangleIBB.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    rectangleISB = rectangleIBB.asShortBuffer();
    rectangleISB.put(rectangleISA);
    rectangleISB.position(0);

    ByteBuffer textureCBB = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCFA.length * 4);
    textureCBB.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureCFB = textureCBB.asFloatBuffer();
    textureCFB.put(textureCFA);
    textureCFB.position(0);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)  {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    checkError("glViewport");
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.setLookAtM(myViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.frustumM(myProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

    aPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
    checkError("glGetAttribLocation");

    uMVPLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uMVP");
    checkError("glGetUniformLocation");

    aTextureCoordLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aTextureCoord");
    checkError("glGetAttribLocation");

    uSampler1Location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uSampler1");
    checkError("glGetUniformLocation");

    uSampler2Location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uSampler2");
    checkError("glGetUniformLocation");

    int[] textures = new int[2];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, textures, 0);
    checkError("glGenTextures");

    textureId1 = textures[0];
    textureId2 = textures[1];

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId1);
    checkError("glBindTexture");

    InputStream is1 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.brick1);
    Bitmap img1;
    try  {
        img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1);
    }finally  {
        try {
            is1.close();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    }
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img1, 0);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId2);
    checkError("glBindTexture");

    InputStream is2 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.brick2);
    Bitmap img2;
    try  {
        img2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
    }finally  {
        try  {
            is2.close();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    }
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img2, 0);

    GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)  {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkError("glClear");

    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
    checkError("glUseProgram");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    checkError("glActiveTexture");
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId1);
    checkError("glBindTexture");

    GLES20.glUniform1i(uSampler1Location, 0);
    checkError("glUniform1i");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    checkError("glActiveTexture");
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId2);
    checkError("glBindTexture");

    GLES20.glUniform1i(uSampler2Location, 1);
    checkError("glUniform1i");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(myRotateMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(myRotateMatrix, 0, touchX, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(myRotateMatrix, 0, touchY, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(myMVPMatrix, 0, myViewMatrix, 0, myRotateMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(myMVPMatrix, 0, myProjectionMatrix, 0, myMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, rectangleVFB);
    checkError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
    checkError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoordLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, textureCFB);
    checkError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordLocation);
    checkError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVPLocation, 1, false, myMVPMatrix, 0);
    checkError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, rectangleISB);
    checkError("glDrawElements");
}
```

Comment: Since those code snippets look quite reasonable you should show some more code, maybe the whole shaders, and some more initialization and rendering code. And make sure your textures are complete (use `GL_LINEAR` filtering if they don't have mipmaps), but since you say they work individually, I guess they are complete.

Comment: First of all : it is a pleasure to have your comment :D thanks a lot Sir for commenting, and here is the code below:

Comment: **[SOLVED]**  In OpenGL ES 2.0, after every call to `glBindTexture` and before `texImage2D` the **parameters** for that texture have to be specified seperately, so if there are 2 textures (as in multitexturing) then it will require 4 `glTexParameterf` each for texture 1 and 2, total **8**

Comment: Yes, the texture parameters are neither global nor per-unit state, but per-texture state. But you don't neccessarily need to specify them before `glTexImage`, just after `glBindTexture`, of course. So one of the textures indeed tried to use mipmap filtering without having complete images for all mipmap levels. Feel free to post (and accept) an answer to your own question if you solved it yourself.

Comment: it seems that you have solved your own question, its ok to answer your own question and accept that answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 2.0, after every call to `glBindTexture` and before `texImage2D` the parameters for that texture have to be specified seperately.

So, if there are 2 textures (as in multitexturing) then it will require 4 `glTexParameterf` each for texture 1 and 2, total 8.